# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor Intellisense not working on XP SP 3 , VS 2010 Pro Trial

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-xp, intellisense

Razor intellisense is not working for me. I do not have Resharper installed and I downloaded both the vs 2010 pro trial and asp.net mvc 3 release this week. Everything is working fine except I get no intellisense.

Is there something related to the trial or xp sp 3 that could be causing issues?
Is there a log or something I can look at to provide information to troubleshoot?

EDIT: I don't see a datetime anywhere on this so I wanted to emphasize this was installed 3/1/2011.
I have tried deleting the ReflectedSchemas folder and resetting my vs2010 settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after a grueling 6 hours of uninstall issues.

I uninstalled all the MVC3 compnonents along with VS 2008 MVC2 tools which I did not realize I had.

I had a horrible time with the uninstall and reinstall. I had to constantly open Task Manager and stop the devenv.exe process as it would hang after uninstalls and installs would complete. Sometimes this would prevent the uninstall/install but eventually everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

after spending hours of install/deinstall stuff to get the razor-editor installed on my production machine (that did not work) - I finally managed to get it going.

All I did was grab the VS2010 SP1 RTM, install it and then reinstall the latest ASP.NET MVC 3 package - no previous deinstall.

And finally I see the razor-editor .... now only if I could get a working Async CTP ;)

Answer (score 0):

I Only had to uninstall MVC2 for vs.net 2010 and the intellisense started working again.